# non-static method add(e) cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, коллекции

Помогите решить проблему. Не могу понять, в чем моя ошибка. class ProductSearchSrvice находиться в отдельном классе.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Lab10 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<ProductSearchSrvice> list = new ArrayList<>();

        ProductSearchSrvice shop_1 = new ProductSearchSrvice("Rozetka");
        ProductSearchSrvice shop_2 = new ProductSearchSrvice("OLX");
        ProductSearchSrvice shop_3 = new ProductSearchSrvice("HIKVISION");

        List.add(shop_1);
        List.add(shop_2);
        List.add(shop_3);
    }
}

class ProductSearchSrvice {
    private String name;

    public ProductSearchSrvice(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ProductSearchSrvice{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: Не поняла. В чем проблема?

Comment: Ааа, все поняла, какая большая буква. Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 1):

Вы в строчке

```
   List.add(shop_1);
```

Вызываете не выше созданную коллекцию, а интерфейс List

Правильно добавлять будет так

```
   list.add(shop_1);
```

Вот решение для вашего случая.

Его конечно можно упростить и усовершенствовать, но мне, увы, неизвестны полные требования вашей лабораторной работы, поэтому пусть будет так.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;

public class Lab10 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProductSearchSrvice shop_1 = new ProductSearchSrvice("Rozetka");
        ProductSearchSrvice shop_2 = new ProductSearchSrvice("OLX");
        ProductSearchSrvice shop_3 = new ProductSearchSrvice("HIKVISION");

        Collection<ProductSearchSrvice> searchServices = addData(shop_1, shop_2, shop_3);
    }

    private static Collection<ProductSearchSrvice> addData(ProductSearchSrvice... items) {
        return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(items));
    }

}

class ProductSearchSrvice {
    private String name;

    public ProductSearchSrvice(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ProductSearchSrvice{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

А вот небольшое объяснение.

В языке java существует модификатор static. Этим модификатором могут быть помечены поля, классы, методы. [Здесь](https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/3.4.php) на русском более-менее объяснено подробно с примерами.

Суть статических полей в том, что они не привязаны к объекту, а привязаны к классу. Соответственно, их копий не может быть больше чем 1 у одного типа объектов (они же привязаны к классу, а не объекту).

Помимо прочих особенностей у статических методов есть такое понятие как статический контекст.

При выполнении кода в нестатическом контексте всегда есть объект, с которым идет работа в данный момент. Например, для нестатического метода это объект, у которого он был вызван.

**Со статическим контекстом ассоциированных объектов нет (помним про привязку к классу). А если нет ассоциированных объектов, то и пользоваться нестатическими конструкциями нельзя. Можно только ссылаться на статические поля и вызывать статические методы. Либо обращаться к объектам через ссылки на них, полученные в результате вызова конструктора или в качестве аргумента методы и т.п.**

Иными словами **вы не можете вызывать нестатические методы из статического контекста (об этом красноречиво сообщает ошибка)**.

Вот конструкторы и статические методы - пожалуйста, объекты созданные в статическом контексте - полностью в вашем распоряжении.

Answer (score 0):

Примерный перевод ошибки:

> Нельзя обратиться к не-статическому методу add(e) из статического контекста

Ошибка возникает из-за того, что вы пытаетесь вызывать метод `add` у интерфейса `List`, а не у объекта (`list`). Обращение к методу через класс или интерфейс вместо объекта - это и есть обращение из статического контекста. Т.к. метод `add` не статический, это вызывает ошибку.

В вашем коде нужно просто заменить `List` на `list` при добавлении элементов:

```
list.add(shop_1);
list.add(shop_2);
list.add(shop_3);
```